# Convert string to datetime on any language Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string in the format yyyymmddhhmmss that I need to convert to a date in Excel.

I have used the trick from Excel [Magic Trick 1076: Convert Date-Time Values to Serial Numbers w TEXT & Custom Number Format]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_SdXBT91aU

This works on an English System. However if I use the same trick on a Japanese system it does not work.

Is there a formula that will work on any language Excel using the function TEXT?

I know about using =Date()+Time() but it a long formula to write. Are there alternatives

Comment: I.e. you need to parse date in `yyyymmddhhmmss` format?

Comment: I get the date in format yyyymmddhhmmss and need to convert it to an excel date(it can be the number because I will apply the required format for date) Ex 20150503121420 => 03-MAY-2015 12:14:20. I have used the format 0000-00-00 00:00:00 that works on english

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really stick to `Date+Time`:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))+TIME(MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2),MID(A1,13,2))
```

Comment: I was afraid of this answer :(